# Системные вызовы... brk vs sbrk в частности

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ассемблер, gnu, syscall

Изучаю программинг под Linux, в частности системные вызовы :)

Многочасовые поиски нормального справочника по системным вызовам завершились, по сути, тремя ссылками:

- http://linuxdoc.ru/sys-doc.html
- http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/qrc/linux%20system%20call%20quick%20reference.pdf
- http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/

Всё остальное - примерно то же самое, только с разным дизайном. Ну или учебник какой-нибудь о Unix в целом (хоть и на русском).

Так вот, на практике придётся использовать все 3 справочника...

1. В первом находить нужную функцию и читать её описание (неплохо, что там всё по-русски).
2. Во втором находить номер функции по названию.
3. Третий использовать, когда информации из 1-го недостаточно (там расписано подробнее и кол-во функций значительно больше... и даже исходники есть).

У кого есть, киньте, плиз, ссылкой на удобный, полный, структурированный справочник, в котором будут указаны (**важно!**) номера функций и значения констант (типа **EBADF** и т.д., т.к. нужно для ассемблера). Что дескриптор стандартного ввода = 0, а вывода = 1 я уже понял, но сдаётся мне, есть там ещё куча подобных штук, искать которые опять же придётся в example'ах на просторах всея интернета, что не очень удобно... А если там ещё и примеры использования будут, то будет вообще супер (хотя не критично).

---

***В частности, вот такой вопрос у меня возник***: **brk** и **sbrk** вроде разные функции. А номер функции (**eax**) как будто один и тот же... Как это может быть? В чём подвох? Или система по значению передаваемого параметра определяет (типа > 0x8000000, значит **brk**, иначе **sbrk**)?

Comment: Ну допустим, я нашёл этот h-файл (правда, по другому пути, ну ок). Смотрим функцию write: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html
В описании куча констант: RLIMIT_FSIZE, EAGAIN, EBADF и т.д. В **unistd.h** их нет. Где их искать? Поиск по всем файлам всей папки include? В мануале названий заголовочных файлов, в которых они прописаны, нет... Ерунда какая-то...
В Windows хоть понятно где искать, в MSDN прописан список h-файлов. p.s. ...А кому я ответил? Сообщение уже потёрли...

Comment: Вообще говоря, чтобы использовать определения для EAGAIN, EBADF и проч., нужно включить заголовок `<errno.h>`. Если хочется выяснить реальное значение константы, можно заглянуть в один из перечисленных мной ниже файлов. Макрос RLIMIT_FSIZE должен быть определён где-то внутри `<unistd.h>`

Comment: man-ы и исходники (grep первейший инструмент). Мне, например, эта реализация для Linux http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree нравится

Comment: А из книжек я бы посоветовал http://www.spbk-spo.com/Professional/matematika_i_informatika/Lav_Linux_syst.pdf и http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/17925734/ того же автора (ссылка на текст сходу не нагуглилась)

Comment: @avp  `git grep` уж скорее.

Answer (score 3):

Зачастую, самой полной документацией является исходный код. Например,

- Номера системных вызовов можно найти в файле `/usr/include/asm/unistd.h`. Для каждой архитектуры номера разнятся, поэтому этот заголовок включает другие в зависимости от определённых макросов. В частности, архитектуры i386 и amd64 имеют несколько различающиеся список номеров и [соглашения о вызовах](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212/5000805).
- Значения макросов для **errno** разбросаны по разным файлам. Но `/usr/include/errno.h` включает их все. В *glibc* это, в основном, такие:

  - `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h`
  - `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/errno.h`
- Судя по тем же исходникам *glibc*, как такового вызова **sbrk** не существует — это надстройка над **brk**. Смотрите файл `misc/sbrk.c` в пакете с исходного кода *glibc*. (Получить можно командой `apt source glibc`). Кстати говоря, исходный код функции **brk** библиотеки *glibc* находится в файле `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/ia64/brk.S` для 64-ёх битной архитектуры ПК; это просто оболочка на ассемблере для реального системного вызова.

---

Вообще говоря, мне кажется более рациональным не записывать жёстко константы в ассемблерный код, а просто включить макроопределения из `<errno.h>` или `<unistd.h>`. GNU Assembler поддерживает сишный препроцессор, так что можно просто подключить эти заголовки директивой **#include**.

Comment: Моё мнение: всё это полезно лишь для обучения, но не для написания реального кода в продакшен.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. А где вообще можно почитать о том, какие файлы нужно подключать для использования того или иного вызова и используемых констант? Вот в MSDN всё понятно: подробно описана работа каждой функции, все заголовочные файлы и пр. А здесь?

Comment: @JinX, руководства из второй секции. Набираете `man 2 имя_вызова`. Какой заголовок нужно подключать, указано в разделе «Синтаксис» («Synopsis»). В принципе, достаточно одного `<unistd.h>`. Его даже можно влючать в ассемблерные листинги для *gas*.

Comment: И я всё-таки так и не понял, как вызывать **sbrk**? Так же, как и **brk**, по тому же номеру или что? Файла /usr/include/misc/sbrk.c и не нашёл ни в установленном Ubuntu, ни здесь: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/include/misc. Как, собственно, и brk.S (искал даже по всему диску эти файлы).

Comment: в **Synopsys** к write указан лишь **unistd.h**, в котором нет ни RLIMIT_FSIZE, ни EBADF и пр...

Comment: Файл `misc/sbrk.c` не устанавливается в систему. Нужно скачать исходники *glibc*. Эта функция оттуда. Если вы хотите вызвать её из ассемблера, то нужно её вызывать как и все остальные функции с помощью `call sbrk`, предварительно записав аргументы.

Comment: По поводу констант: не совсем понял, зачем они вам нужны. Если для написания программы, то лучше подключить заголовки `<asm/unistd.h>` и `<asm/errno.h>` (чуть выше я ошибся) и использовать макросы оттуда.

Comment: не понимаю... как я могу сделать **call sbrk**, если такая функция нигде не задана? Даже в том же **unistd.h** её нет с таким названием...

Comment: Вот я только что скачал http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/plain/include/unistd.h (там есть **void \*sbrk**), добавил в исходник **#include unistd.h** и попытался скомпилировать исходник, содержащий **call sbrk**. Компилятор хавает. А вот **ld.gold.exe** (я пишу из-под Windows, копилирую MinGW64) пишет: *error: undefined reference to 'sbrk'*. Пробовал то же и с write, и с _sbrk, _write - результат один...

Comment: Кстати, как же можно использовать **#include**, когда с символа **#** начинаются комментарии...? :)

Comment: Хм… но если имя файла оканчивается на большую `S`, то вначале он будет обработан препроцессором Си. http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/gas И минуточку, какой ассемблер вы используете? Верно ли я понимаю, что наличие метки `[ubuntu]`, означает, что вопрос по этой системе?

Comment: И мне кажется, вам будет удобнее целиком получить все исходники *glibc* с [официального сайта проекта](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html)

Comment: Вообще, я сишу под убунтой, набираю, например, `gcc test.S`, и GCC всё самостоятельно компонует с libc

Comment: По идее, MinGW, только эмулирует некоторые POSIX совместимые вызовы. Я не знаю точно, как он устроен. Судя по всему, есть существенные отличия...

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Буду думать дальше.